# How to bulk edit Word document so all the Chinese characters are placed in the same vertical position?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-office

[image]

This is the Word document I received. I need to find a way to put all the words into three lines (ideally), where all the Chinese and phonetic symbol lined up vertically. How can I do that?

Comment: I'ts not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Can you give an example of how it should like (the first few lines(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Mark all rows that need the formatting.
2. Display the horizontal Ruler if not visible,
   *(CTRL-Shift+R in LibreOffice-Writer, no 'Word' to check)*
3. Remove or reset ALL **TAB-markers**
4. Add a TAB-**marker** for your two columns (phonetics, Chinese)
5. Make sure there is a TAB-**character** on each line,  just before
   a) the first phonetic character AND
   b) Chinese character